# Pencilblue: Building api around custom object type

Tags: api, rest, custom-object, pencilblue

I'm trying to build an API using pencilblue, but can't figure out how to start. This question is really wide but I'm looking for examples on creating CRUD API with custom object.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at the `sample` plugin and see how it's done there. PB already has a small amount of public plugins, have a look how others do it here: https://pencilblue.org/plugins